# Need to remove square brackets generated by BIML

Tags: oracle, ssis, biml

I am using BIML to create SSIS packages to load data from Oracle tables.

When assigning the results of table.GetColumnList to a source component, the oracle driver complains about the brackets [] returned by GetColumnList. How could I remove them from the query expression?

In other words:

BIML is returning this 
Select [Field1] from [GL].[table2]

and I need this:
Select Field1 from GL.table2

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance,
Waldemar

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using REPLACE(). In your case you simply apply replace() to the string/value you are selecting:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('Select [Field1] from [GL].[table2]', '[', ''), ']', '') final_val 
 FROM dual
/
```

Output:

```
 Select Field1 from GL.table2
```